# Text substitution in file while expanding variables, using them as string literals, and adding a newline

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace anything that looks like

```
if (Thing *thing1 = Stuff) {
```

with

```
Thing *thing1 = Stuff;
if (thing1) {
```

Essentially take declarations out of if statements.

I have all the parts and I see that they're correct, I'm just having trouble with the replacement

```
grep '  if (.* = .*) {' $file | while read -r line ; do

    inside="$( echo "$line" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 );"
    object="$( echo $( echo "$inside" | cut -d "*" -f2 | cut -d "=" -f1 ) | xargs )"
    newIF="    if ($object) {"
    replacement="$inside\n$newIF"

    line_regexp="$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')"
    replacement_regexp="$(echo "$replacement" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')"

    sed -i.bak "s/$line_regexp/$replacement_regexp/g" $file


done
```

Edit thanks to: https://superuser.com/questions/422459/substitution-in-text-file-without-regular-expressions

Now I just have to figure out how to turn "\n" into an actual newline

Comment: Would be pretty straightforward in python? Any reason you are using `sed` from the outset?

Comment: @beroe I have use bash. Uhh pretty much because I'm not sure how else to do the text replacement? I'm open to other options

Comment: try `echo 'if (Thing *thing1 = Stuff) {' | perl -pe 's/if\s*(\(.*\*(\S+).*\))\s*{/$1;\nif ($2) {/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sed should work for you:

```
$ sed -n 's/if (\([^ ]* \*\([^ ]*\) = [^)]*\)) {/\1;\nif (\2) {/p' <<< "if (Thing *thing1 = Stuff) {"
Thing *thing1 = Stuff;
if (thing1) {
```